# Coding test JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

A rectangle is called rectilinear if its edges are all parallel to coordinate axes. Such a rectangle can be described by specifying the coordinates of its lower-left and upper-right corners. Write a function:

```
 function solution($K, $L, $M, $N, $P, $Q, $R, $S);
```

that, given eight integers representing two rectilinear rectangles *(one with lower-left corner (K, L) and upper-right corner (M, N), and another with lower-left corner (P, Q) and upper-right corner (R, S))*, returns the area of the sum of the rectangles. If the rectangles intersect, the area of their intersection should be counted only once. The function should return −1 if the area of the sum exceeds 2,147,483,647.

For example, given integers:

```
 K = -4    L = 1      M = 2     N = 6
  P = 0     Q = -1     R = 4     S = 3
```

the function should return 42.

The area of the first rectangle is 30, the area of the second is 16 and the area of their intersection is 4.

Assume that:

```
    K, L, M, N, P, Q, R and S are integers within the range [−2147483648..2147483647];
    K < M;
    L < N;
    P < R;
    Q < S.
```

Complexity:

```
    expected worst-case time complexity is O(1);
    expected worst-case space complexity is O(1).
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow show us what you tried so far...

Answer (score -1):

```js
function solution(k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s) {
  var rectOneArea = area(k, l, m, n);
  var rectTwoArea = area(p, q, r, s);
  var overLapArea = intersectingArea(k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s);
  return rectOneArea + rectTwoArea - overLapArea;
}


function intersectingArea(k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s) {
  var xOverlap = Math.min(m, r) - Math.max(k, p);
  var yOverlap = Math.min(n, s) - Math.max(l, q);
  return xOverlap * yOverlap;
}


function area(a, b, c, d) {
  var width = Math.abs(a - c);
  var height = Math.abs(b - d);
  return width * height;
}


console.log(solution(-4, 1, 2, 6, 0, -1, 4, 3));
```

This is just straight up implementation of a simple math problem...
You already know the geometry  behind it i.e. A1 + A2 - overlap.

The only thing you need to figure out is calculating the intersecting area.

I don't know why this was tagged as PHP and JavaScript but if you want a PHP solution it should be simple to write it using this as a reference.